# General form for the given integral

Tags: calculus, integration

We are developing an application which can solve integration problems on a given interval. For that, we need a general form of the integral which we can easily convert to code. The integral is:

$$\displaystyle\int_a^b \frac{x^n}{1+x^k} \, dx$$

Here, the user will gives input the value of $a$, $b$, $n$ and $k$. And the application solves the integral for them. But, there is no general simplified form for this type of functions at our hand right now. How should I proceed that?

Comment: Please have a look at [here](https://planetmath.org/integrationofdifferentialbinomial). Surely, you will need it when solving the corresponding indefinite integral as well as writing the codes!

Comment: Just to be sure : $n$ and $k$ are integers ?

Comment: Yes. They are integers